# Clearing a jQgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

How I can delete all value into a grid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [clearGridData](http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/_2eb0fi5wo.htm) method

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use `clearGridData` method of jqGrid you should be careful if you have additional events added to the grid elements. It could be required to use additional parameter `deepempty: true` in such situations.

In general you can delete jqGrid like any other elements on the page with respect of `jQuery.remove` function. The method `clearGridData` were introduced to speed up such removable in standard situations. On the other side `jQuery.remove` works slowly but very safe independent of any kind of manually added events.